# IIS 6.0 ignores my custom error settings

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, custom-error-pages

Help I have added the following configuration to my `web.config` file:

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/errors/CustomError.aspx">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Errors/PageNotFound.aspx" />        
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/PageNotFound.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
```

And in `system.webServer`

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
    <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/CustomError.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/CustomError.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
```

I don't want my web server to announce 403/404 for security reason.

After making the above changes however I'm still getting 403 forbidden message when attempting to browse a directory.

The only thing that works is configuring it from IIS:

[image]

How can I tell IIS to go look at the web.config settings instead of the IIS one? It seems like the error is thrown too early in the pipeline - it's completely ignoring the web.config and the rest of asp.net plumbing.

Also the error is definitely not getting into the Glogal.Asax.cs `Application_Error` function. Is there a way to make sure the error is always routed through asp.net?

Comment: Do you have a Application created under virtual directory in IIS?

Comment: Yes that's why when set directly through the GUI the custom error page works